# UISearchBar: changing background color of input field

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm trying to change the background color of input field of UISearchBar.It's the rounded view where you input text to search, the default color is white. I would like to change it to gray

I tried:

```
for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subView;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    }
```

But it doesn't work :(

I also tried to insert an image view to TextField but it seems the rounded view is separate from TextField. So, any clues?

Comment: u should create searchbar in code not in interfacebuilder.i had same issue while create from IB.so use code to create searchbar

Comment: AHHHH, I did it! I set the textField.background with an image and it worked, yay!

Answer (score 11):

=)

```
for (UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews) {
    for(id field in subView.subviews){
        if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)field;
            [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Look at the function :

```
[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2 and iOS 9 you can call:

```
UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrey()
```

Swift 3:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrey()
```

Comment: As @enreas mentioned, the solution is hence: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42626728/2229062

Answer (score 3):

Solution in Swift 3:

```
if let txfSearchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField {
        txfSearchField.borderStyle = .none
        txfSearchField.backgroundColor = .lightGray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the extension worked in swift4:

```
extension UISearchBar {

    var input : UITextField? {

        return findInputInSubviews(of: self)
    }

    func findInputInSubviews(of view: UIView) -> UITextField? {
        guard view.subviews.count > 0 else { return nil }
        for v in view.subviews {
            if v.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                return v as? UITextField
            }
            let sv = findInputInSubviews(of: v)
            if sv != nil { return sv }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

usage:

```
searchBar?.input?.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
```