# iOS tint textfield background of Search bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search

In iOS (support for 5.x+) what is the easiest way to change the white background color of the UISearchBar textfield to be a different color? There is no tintColor property on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISearchBar: changing background color of input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229147/uisearchbar-changing-background-color-of-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this method as,

```
[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage: forState:];
```

In versions prior to iOS 5, you can use a category as,

```
@implementation UISearchBar (BackgroundColor)

- (UITextField *)field {
    // HACK: This may not work in future iOS versions
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            return (UITextField *)subview;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)setTextBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color {
    self.field.backgroundColor = color;
}

@end
```

Comment: Awesome I'll give that a try this weekend. Thanks for the quick reply! I'll mark this as the accepted answer once I try it out.

Comment: As a side question, do you know if you can change the little search bar magnifying glass icon easily?

Comment: @babolatpdtp, I think we can. Let me check. How about raising that as a separate question so that others who are trying to do the same can also benefit.

Comment: You can use for iOS 5 app as mentioned below. For apps which uses OS version before this, this wont work. - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state; But I would suggest you to anyway raise as a new question so that as I mentioned above, it will benefit others who are trying to find answer for the same question.

Comment: You sir are awesome. Thanks for the quick replies. I'm surprised this hasn't really come up much. Fair point in creating a new question, I'll do that now and link back to this as well.

Comment: @babolatpdtp, Thanks. I have added the answer in the other question which you have raised. Please accept there to mark it as a helpful solution.