# How to change inside background color of UISearchBar component on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, customization, uisearchbar, background-color

I know how to remove/change `UISearchBar` background color around search field:

```
[[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

[image: achieved UISearchBar customization]

But don't know how to do this inside it like that:

[image: desired UISearchBar customization]

This needs to be compatible with iOS 4.3+.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5557255/1570343

Comment: This is not ok. I want to get rid of white color inside component. Take a look at the question...

Comment: @BorutTomazin test my code its work fine and here you can change the searchBar icon with 4 types of icon which i define in answer but you want to use white searchbar so just add image on the searchbaricon with another white searchbar icon and also add image as a background of UITextField of searchbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISearchBar: changing background color of input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229147/uisearchbar-changing-background-color-of-input-field)

Comment: For Swift 3.
I found a solution here: [**Customize textfield easily**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40105165/4593553)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this code to change the searchBar's `UITextField` backgroundImage:

```
UITextField *searchField;
NSUInteger numViews = [searchBar.subviews count];
for (int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
    if ([[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
if (searchField) {
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]]; //set your gray background image here
    [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
}
```

Use the below code to change the `UISearchBarIcon`:

```
 UIImageView *searchIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourSearchBarIconImage"]];
searchIcon.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 24, 24);
[searchBar addSubview:searchIcon];
[searchIcon release];
```

Also, to change the searchBar icon you can use the following built-in method on `UISearchBar` (which is available from **iOS 5+**):

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state
```

Here you can set 4 types of `UISearchBarIcon` i.e.:

1. `UISearchBarIconBookmark`
2. `UISearchBarIconClear`
3. `UISearchBarIconResultsList`
4. `UISearchBarIconSearch`

I hope this help you...

Comment: @BorutTomazin i just add the code for change the textfield backgroundcolor of searchbar and when i get output for search icon i'll also post code hope it help you...

Comment: This way is not a good way to do it. It can easily break your app in coming iOS updates. *EDIT* Sorry, just saw that the OP needed it to be compatible with iOS 4.

Comment: @Accatyyc this is give perfact output which he wants and its problem occure in bellow the version of 5.0 or 4.3 so its fine and if you have a solution then post the code dude i have this solution which may useful ...

Comment: not the best solution. see *EvGeniy Ilyin*'s, which is way bellow the many ugly solutions. (cmd+F, search this page.) `UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(white‌​Image, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 47):

Just customize the text field itself.

I am simply doing this and it works fine for me (iOS 7).

```
UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This way you don't need to create an image, size it, etc...

Comment: This would likely be considered using private API, so I'd be cautious submitting an app with this.

Comment: Like @iWasRobbed mentioned, this is using private API that accesses hidden variable through KVC.

Comment: @iWasRobbed and please take a look at my answer, maybe that will be fine for you

Comment: *cough this can be rejected from Apple because you're accessing private variables cough*

Comment: Still Working in the last ios version

Comment: Best and simple solution! Thnx! =)

Comment: in iOS 13: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Access to UISearchBar's _searchField ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug' .. this is now going to cause app crashes, so you should change the solution to continue getting upvotes!

Comment: iOS 13 gives me:  reason: 'Access to UISearchBar's _searchField ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug'

Comment: Although in iOS 13 onwards there is a public API `_searchBar.searchTextField`

Answer (score 42):

### Details

- Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a), swift 5

[UISearchBar customising sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745002/4488252)

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UISearchBar {
    func getTextField() -> UITextField? { return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField }
    func setTextField(color: UIColor) {
        guard let textField = getTextField() else { return }
        switch searchBarStyle {
        case .minimal:
            textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        case .prominent, .default: textField.backgroundColor = color
        @unknown default: break
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
//searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
view.addSubview(searchBar)
searchBar.placeholder = "placeholder"
searchBar.setTextField(color: UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3))
```

### Result 1

```
 searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent // or default
```

[image]

### Result 2

```
 searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
```

[image]

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
        //searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
        view.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.placeholder = "placeholder"
        searchBar.setTextField(color: UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3))
    }
}
```

Comment: This was killing me...thanks for pointing out that for minimal you had to do layer.backgroundColor...

Comment: One interesting problem with this solution is that when type is .minimal and one sets the background to white -> the background becomes grey. this is due to the fact that the top of the view is taken by an image named _UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView

Comment: Can't understand. Can you show the code? I have no problem with setting searchBar.backgroundColor = .white.

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thank you.

Comment: **For guys looking for a better solution, I recommend you read `EvGeniy Ilyin`'s, which is way bellow the many ugly solutions.**  (cmd+F, search this page.)    `UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(whiteImage, for: .normal)`

Comment: iOS 11 for minimal searcher, setting .layer background doesn't work anymore. It seems there is an additional view on top of the textfield.

Comment: why we use layer for minimal searchBarStyle .? because when I remove backgroundColor without layer it not set the color that's why .

Comment: @ApoorvKhatreja it is possible. I will wait for the official Xcode release and then update the code.

Answer (score 39):

**Solution which doesn't involve any private API ! :)**

Currently ([probably since iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:) ) you can do this, for simply one colour cases, in this way:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but please keep in mind that as it basis on appearance the change will be global for the app (it can be an advantage or a disadvantage of the solution).

For Swift you can use (it will work for iOS 9 and above):

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
}
```

You do not need `#available` if your project supports iOS 9 and newer.

If you need to support earlier versions of iOS and want to use Swift take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift) question.

Comment: SearchBarStyle should be default! :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, not even on default or minimal style (iOS 8).

Comment: Works but iOS 9 only. Here is the Swift equivalent: UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

Comment: @MaxMacLeod, thanks I have updated my answer based on what you posted

Answer (score 24):

According to the [UISearchBar documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

You should use this function for iOS 5.0+.

```
- (void)setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Usage example:

```
[mySearchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Sadly, in iOS 4 you need to revert to less sophisticated methods. See other answers.

Comment: This is fine if I am targeting only iOS 5+ devices.

Answer (score 20):

As Accatyyc says for iOS5+ use setSearchFieldBackgroundImage, but you either need to create a graphic, or do the following:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
// create context with transparent background
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

// Add a clip before drawing anything, in the shape of an rounded rect
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)
                            cornerRadius:5.0] addClip];
[[UIColor grayColor] setFill];

UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 17):

what about apple way?

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(myImage, for: .normal)
```

### you can set any image on your design!

But if you want create all programmaticle, you ca do this

---

my solution on **Swift 3**

```
let searchFieldBackgroundImage = UIImage(color: .searchBarBackground, size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 30))?.withRoundCorners(4)
UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(searchFieldBackgroundImage, for: .normal)
```

where i use helpers extension

```
public extension UIImage {

    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }

    public func withRoundCorners(_ cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        context?.beginPath()
        context?.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context?.closePath()
        context?.clip()

        draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return image;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is surely the best and the most graceful way. Thanks! Saved my life.

Comment: This is the correct way. I was just about to post a version of this. Good work! Very Complete!

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but this sets the background image of the entire search bar and not the just the background image inside the text field

Comment: Finally a solution that doesn't use the private API! I went with UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal) to completely remove the grey image

Answer (score 14):

To do this on iOS 13+,

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = // your color here
```

Do note that by default the `searchTextField.borderStyle` is set to `roundedRect`, which applies a slight gray overlay on top of the color that you will set. If this is undesired, do

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
```

This will get rid of the gray overlay, but also get rid of the rounded corners.

Comment: how to you change the place holder text color for iOS 13 ?

Answer (score 7):

I've found this to be the best way to customize the appearance of various search bar attributes in Swift 2.2 and iOS 8+ using `UISearchBarStyle.Minimal`

```
searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // color of bar button items
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.fadedBlueColor() // color of text field background
searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() // color of box surrounding text field
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

// Edit search field properties
if let searchField = searchBar.valueForKey("_searchField") as? UITextField  {
  if searchField.respondsToSelector(Selector("setAttributedPlaceholder:")) {
    let placeholder = "Search"
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: placeholder)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: placeholder.characters.count)
    let color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.7)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15)!, range: range)
    searchField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString

    searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    searchField.textColor = .whiteColor()
  }
}

// Set Search Icon
let searchIcon = UIImage(named: "search-bar-icon")
searchBar.setImage(searchIcon, forSearchBarIcon: .Search, state: .Normal)

// Set Clear Icon
let clearIcon = UIImage(named: "clear-icon")
searchBar.setImage(clearIcon, forSearchBarIcon: .Clear, state: .Normal)

// Add to nav bar
searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

without using private API's:

```
for (UIView* subview in [[self.searchBar.subviews lastObject] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)subview;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't use private API but it still relies on private implementation details (i.e. the internal view hierarchy of the search bar). This implementation could change at any time.

Answer (score 6):

try this in iOS13 in swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
searchBar.barTintColor = .systemIndigo
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 5):

For Changing Only Color :

```
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

For Applying Background Image :

```
[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:
                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Searchbox.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to set the appearance of the `UITextField` inside `UISearchBar`

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Comment: sorry @JulianKról I just saw your answer now, didn't notice it before

Comment: no problem, just noticed yours, and checked how it is different :)

Comment: duplicates previous answer

Answer (score 4):

Just traverse all views using a category method (verified in iOS 7 and doesn't use private API):

```
@implementation UISearchBar (MyAdditions)

- (void)changeDefaultBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color {
  for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subSubview in subview.subviews) {
      if ([subSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)subSubview;
        searchField.backgroundColor = color;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

@end
```

So after importing the category into your class, just use it like:

```
[self.searchBar changeDefaultBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Keep in mind, if you put this *immediately* after the `[[UISearchBar alloc] init]` line, it won't work yet since the subviews of the search bar are still being created.  Put it a few lines down after you setup the rest of the search bar.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self searchSubviewsForTextFieldIn:self.searchBar] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

- (UITextField*)searchSubviewsForTextFieldIn:(UIView*)view
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        return (UITextField*)view;
    }
    UITextField *searchedTextField;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        searchedTextField = [self searchSubviewsForTextFieldIn:subview];
        if (searchedTextField) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return searchedTextField;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the Swift version ( swift 2.1 /IOS 9 )

```
for view in searchBar.subviews {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview .isKindOfClass(UITextField) {
            let textField: UITextField = subview as! UITextField
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This had no effect for me. But setting the **textField.layer.backgroundColor** does change the background color.

Answer (score 3):

Searchbar now has a new instance property SearchTextField starting iOS 13,
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/3175433-searchtextfield

```
if(@available(iOS 13, *))
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
else{
    //API that supports below iOS 13
    //This will set it for all the UISearchBars in your application
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 13, Swift 5**

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .gray
 searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = .white
 searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 9 use this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Remove lag on oppening the keyboard for the first time
UITextField *lagFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:lagFreeField];
[lagFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
[lagFreeField resignFirstResponder];
[lagFreeField removeFromSuperview];

//searchBar background color change
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
for subview in searchBar.subviews {
    for innerSubview in subview.subviews {
        if innerSubview is UITextField {
            innerSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.YOUR_COLOR_HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3+, use this:**

```
for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews {

    for subViewOne in subView.subviews {

        if let textField = subViewOne as? UITextField {

           subViewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

           //use the code below if you want to change the color of placeholder
           let textFieldInsideUISearchBarLabel = textField.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
                textFieldInsideUISearchBarLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 4, I would recommend that you only do this, no additional code needed:

```
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
self.searchBar.barStyle = .black
```

You can also change .prominent to .minimal should you not want the outer background to be grey.

Answer (score 1):

**Use it to update search textfield backgroud_color for xcode10 and xcode11 working fine for me**

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

@EvGeniy Ilyin EvGeniy Ilyin's solution is the best.
I wrote an **Objective-C** version based on this solution.

Create a `UIImage` category, and advertise two class methods in **UIImage+YourCategory.h**

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color withSize:(CGRect)imageRect;
+ (UIImage *)roundImage:(UIImage *)image withRadius:(CGFloat)radius;
```

Implement methods in **UIImage+YourCategory.m**

```
// create image with your color
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color withSize:(CGRect)imageRect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, imageRect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

// get a rounded-corner image from UIImage instance with your radius
+ (UIImage *)roundImage:(UIImage *)image withRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    rect.size = image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                cornerRadius:radius];
    [path addClip];
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Make your own `UISearchBar` in your `ViewController`

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 30.0);
UIImage *colorImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor yourColor] withSize:rect];
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage roundImage:colorImage withRadius:4.0];
[yourSearchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:finalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me.

```
- (void)setupSearchBar
{
    [self.searchBar setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
    [self.searchBar setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
    [self.searchBar setPlaceholder:FOLocalizedString(@"search", nil)];
    [self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor myGreyBGColor]];
    [self.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor myGreyBGColor]];
    [self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This helped me to change the background color of textField in searchbar.

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: Pleas don't just put some code, provide some explanation also.