# make UItextfield to function like UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

I want to change the looks of `UISearchBar`: So,

If there's a way by which I can make my  `UITextField`(in a custom background for search) to function like `UISearchBar` ? or subclassing and overriding the `- (void)layoutSubviews` is the only way ?

Kindly tell How to subclass it !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can change the `UISearchBar` background using this bellow code..

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkyBackground.jpeg"]];
            [searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
```

From this code you can set image or anything else for background of `UISearchBar`.

Also see my this answer with some other functionality to change the searchbar component layout..[How to change inside background color of UISearchBar component on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios/13817915#13817915)

**UPDATE:**

for change the Cancel button appearance use this bellow code...

```
   UIButton *cancelButton = nil;

    for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
            //do something here with this cancel Button
        }
    }
```

Comment: it changes the background but textfield size and and the magnifying glass  and cancel button are still there. That's why I wanted a custom text field to act like UIseachBar

Comment: just set whole background clear and also not able the cancel button to appear ..means enabled = NO

Comment: just like just     [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO]; use this line to hide the cancel button and just do something with this code you will get output which you want ,,, also see my answer which i post the link above .. you can get something from that.. hope its helped you.. :)

Comment: Ok it worked first I removed the background of UIsearchbar then placed my own. Then used the above link of yours to change the background of UItext Field. Now the problem is I need cancel button, how can i access it to change its frame and type

Comment: which, default cancel you want to change??

Comment: either cancel button (yes default one) or the frame of UITextField(I tried, but height and width of textfield in serach bar is 0,0).

Comment: now i update code for change the view or something else for cancel button of searchbar just change the code with your requirement and same as do for textfield.. :) hope this helped you.. Thank you..

Answer (score 6):

Its also possible using UITextFieldDelegates

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{    
NSString *searchString;
if (string.length > 0) {        
    searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text, string];
} else {
   searchString = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];
}
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
resultArray = [[resultTempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter] mutableCopy];

if (!searchString || searchString.length == 0) {

    resultArray = [resultTempArray mutableCopy];
} else {
    if (resultArray.count == 0) {
NSLog(@"No data From Search");
    }
}    
[tableView reloadData];    
return YES;
}
```

Comment: thnQ dude actually i got the same idea but not yet implemented but after seeing yours only i got confirmed that my idea is correct and also there is a small change near CONTAINS it should be SELF CONTAINS otherwise it will crash.....

Answer (score 2):

Filtering using UItextfield delegate methods

```
#pragma mark - UITEXTFIELD DELEGATE METHODS -

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    arrFilterSearch = nil;
    arrFilterSearch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrSearch];
    UITableView *tblView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tblView_Tag];
    [tblView reloadData];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *searchKey = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    arrFilterSearch = nil;
    searchKey = [searchKey stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    if (searchKey.length) {
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname contains[cd] %@", searchKey];
            arrFilterSearch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arrSearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]];
    }
    else
        arrFilterSearch = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrSearch];

    UITableView *tblView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tblView_Tag];
    [tblView reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    self.TextFieldSearch = (UITextField *)[self.Search.subviews lastObject];
    [self.TextFieldSearch removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.TextFieldSearch];
    self.TextFieldSearch.delegate = self;
    self.TextFieldSearch.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    self.TextFieldSearch.keyboardAppearance =  UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    [self.Search removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the UIsearchBar background is one way to get a customized UISearchBar. But if you want limited functionality of searching a table you can have normal text Field and hook up a search button to filter results of tableview in another array and update tabledata with that array.

UIsearchBar's `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`  is almost equivalent to `UItextField's valieChanged IBAction`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the same issue, and I subclassed UISearchBar! Here you go

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];
UITextField *searchField = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
            searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            [searchField setValue:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
             [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"] ];
              searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        }

}
self.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

[image: When entering text]