# Change the background of UISearchBar's textField

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm struggling with this for a while now. Have searched everywhere but the solution provided only works with objective-c. Which consists in

`UITextField *txt = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];`

Although some might say that this is protected API and Apple might refuse an app with such code.

So, now I've tried so many ways to work this out and it's not working at all.
My code is this:

```
searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 30.0))
searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15
searchBar.delegate = self

searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

if floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1{
    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search";
} else {
    // The following "hack" (if we can call that) breaks the UI for different size devices.
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search                                         ";
}
```

This gives me the bizarre result:
[image]

While what I want is just the textfield inside the UISearchBar to have a white background and the SearchBar itself have a cornerRadius of, say, 15.

How can I do this?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: UITextField *searchField = [SearchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
I have already used this code in my app and app it already available in App Store..

Answer (score 32):

You have to access the UITextField inside the UISearchBar. You can do that by 
using `valueForKey("searchField")`

```
var textFieldInsideSearchBar = yourSearchbar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField

textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = yourcolor
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
...
```

there you can change any parameters like textColor or backgroundColor of the UITextField

Comment: you should set style as `Prominent` or `Default.` If you prefer to use `Minimal`, `backgroundColor` is not working.
`searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent // or .Default`

Comment: @fatihyildizhan thanks this is indeed really important to NOT use Minimal style! spent too much time on this....

Answer (score 18):

In Swift 3:

```
if let txfSearchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField {
        txfSearchField.borderStyle = .none
        txfSearchField.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the above answer. 
If you want to keep the search bar style UISearchBarStyleMinimal and change the background of UISearchBar's textField, set the textField's borderStyle to UITextBorderStyleNone

Objective C:

```
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

UITextField *txfSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    txfSearchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    txfSearchField.backgroundColor = yourColor;
```

Comment: I have searched around. This is the solution that really works !

Comment: I concur. This solution works when `UISearchBarStyle` is set to `.minimal`. Tested on iOS 10.3

Answer (score 9):

Swift 5 and iOS 13

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

You can direct change colour of textfield background.

Comment: Warning: ```searchTextField``` is only available after iOS 13.

Answer (score 3):

Add an extension to `UISearchBar` to access its `UITextField`:

```
import UIKit

extension UISearchBar {

    var textField: UITextField? {
        let subViews = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        return (subViews.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField
    }
}
```

Then you can set its properties as you'd expect:

```
searchController.searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor = .red
searchController.searchBar.textField?.tintColor = .yellow
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions when you haven't tried the answer. This doesn't work in iOS 12 for instance.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen could you elaborate on what is "not working"?

Comment: `searchController.searchBar.textField?` is always `nil` in my case

Comment: Besides we can now do `serachBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white` so this answer may have been valid for old SDK's but not in recent SDK's

Answer (score 1):

searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor  = UIColor.white
 searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = UIColor.black

Answer (score 0):

When using iOS 13 or newer, the `searchTextField` property can be directly accessed.

However, setting the `backgroundColor` only works as expected when the `borderStyle` is set to `.none`. This results in a text field without rounded borders. To fix this, use this code:

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.borderStyle = .none
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white // Or any other UIColor
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
```

Comment: The `searchTextField` property has been available on `UISearchBar` since iOS 13.0

Comment: @HangarRash You're right!