# How to change search icon inside UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I am trying to change the search icon inside an UISearchBar in iOS7 and ok, I got it. But is this the best way?

```
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"searchIcon.png"]
            forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
                       state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And the problem is that the image size is not great as the original, I would like to know the correct size to replace the image. I am using an image = 64x64 and an image@2x = 128x128, is it correctly? If so, why my search bar is like this:

[image: SearchBar Icon Issue]

Comment: That's the right code. Does your icon have a big border or does the symbol file the image?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by setting the leftView of the searchField

```
if let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField {
   textFieldInsideSearchBar.leftView = imageView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to Replace the magnifying glass icon in an iPhone UISearchBar with a custom image use this code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchBoxExperimentsViewController : UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

@end




#import "SearchBoxExperimentsViewController.h"

@interface SearchBoxExperimentsViewController (Private)
- (void)setSearchIconToFavicon;
@end


@implementation SearchBoxExperimentsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self setSearchIconToFavicon];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark Private

- (void)setSearchIconToFavicon {
  // Really a UISearchBarTextField, but the header is private.
  UITextField *searchField = nil;
  for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
      searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (searchField) {  
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"favicon.png"];
    UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    searchField.leftView = iView;
    [iView release];
  }  
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do this? `UISearchBar` has an API for setting the icon and it is being used by the OP's code.

Comment: @maddy  Yes i know that there is API Available - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state but through this you can only set 4 types of UISearchBarIcon , 
 There's no public API to change or remove that default icon , see Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios

Comment: Do you think this will fix my problem about the icon size?

Comment: if you want to add custom , search icon in UISearch bar then yes