# Changing the field background in a searchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

I'm creating a app where i want the same searchBar colors as in the Music App in IOS. I'm wondering how do i change the field of the searchBar, i've searched around for this, but could not find anything that works. Here is a image

[image]

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios

Comment: How can this be done using swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var textField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as UITextField
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: Is this not accessing the private API?