# How to change background color of UiSearchBar to black -SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I created UISearchBar programmatically as below and the button appears to be of second image.How to clear the white color of search bar and set background colour to **Black**

```
var categorySearchBar : UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
        categorySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)
        categorySearchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        categorySearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        categorySearchBar.placeholder = "SEARCH"
        categorySearchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(categorySearchBar)
```

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817330/how-to-change-inside-background-color-of-uisearchbar-component-on-ios.

Comment: take a look please at my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555462/3472073

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ***barStyle*** property of **UISearchBar** , if you are using story board you can use Attribute Inspector to change bar style, or use following code segment. It might help mate :)

```
categorySearchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

Comment: Is there a way to change it to any other colour, say red? or a custom colour, such as: `UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 165/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 0.4)` ? thanks

Comment: till now no i guess, for that we have to create custom search bar !