# iOS UISearchBar text field background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customize the text field of the UISearchBar on iOS, but I'm having issues. Using the following method:

```
[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchFieldImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

gives me the image in the text field, but it is TINY. The image is only 40x15 px dimension, and is used for stretching. I'm creating the image as follows:

```
UIImage *searchFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"input_15x40.png"]
                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 19, 7, 20)];
```

However, it seems that this appearance modification doesn't stretch the image - just takes it as is. How can I go about customizing the textfield image of the UISearchBar with a stretchable image?

**EDIT** 
I should say that the bar is stretched horizontally, but it is NOT stretched vertically, and thus is only 15px height.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISearchBar: changing background color of input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229147/uisearchbar-changing-background-color-of-input-field)

Comment: No. At the time this was an issue with the image not stretching vertically to a desired height, as the image itself sets the frame of the view that wraps it. Therefore there is no vertical stretching to be done. The other question you linked deals with simply changing the color of the field - two distinct and separate questions with potentially overlapping answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem that I can see in your code is that you create the var named searchFieldImage and use it as searchField.

This code worked for me:

```
UIImage *searchFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"input_15x40.png"]
              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 19, 7, 20)];

[searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchFieldImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

-

Edit:

In the height, the image will not stretch because the height of the image will set the height of the view that wraps it.

Comment: Edited it, that was a typo sorry :P Have you tried this with an image that is stretched? For some reason is stretches it horizontally, but not vertically when this code is executed. For testing purposes I have placed this code in viewDidLoad: of a UIViewController - could that be an issue?

Comment: I believe that the background adjusts to your image in the height, sorry, your last line confused me, I understood that the Bar is stretched horizontally and not vertically, then I think that you need just the horizontal stretch. Not that the image that is not stretched vertically.

Comment: Ah, damn. Well it seems as if I am doomed here - I'm not sure that there is a method to expand the vertical height. I tried to extract the UITextField subview of the search bar and adjust its frame, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you want, but you can customize an view to adjust to your propose or you can adjust your image to the height you want...

Comment: I ended up just adjusting the image to the desired height since it does not stretch the image vertically

Answer (score 0):

```
let searchTextField = searchBar.valueForKey("_searchField") as? UITextField
searchTextField?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```